# Exended select directory dialog

Tags: c++, .net, interop, marshalling

I am looking for vista style folder browse dialog with abily to choose folder path only.

Looks like that: 
[image]

I have checked the VistaBridge and Microsoft Code Pack API, but there are only dialogs for file opening.

Do you know how to call this dialog or some solutions to customize standart FileBrowseDialogs?
Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to use `SHBrowseForFolder` API to have that Dialog, full example and documentation can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Looks like there are no easy way to add the side bar, back-forvard buttons, search textbox, etc..